# Why can't I access the OpenWRT Web UI in Access Point Only Mode?

Tags: openwrt

I have a main router with a dhcp and dns service.

An **additional router**, a Netgear R7800 Nighthawk X4S, is connected over wire to the main router which I will use to extend the wireless coverage.

Because I have a relatively small simultaneous device count (home network), I decided to use the main router's DHCP and DNS services.

On the additional (aux) router, I stopped the dhcp service and the dns:

```
/etc/init.d/dnsmasq disable && /etc/init.d/dnsmasq stop
/etc/init.d/firewall disable && /etc/init.d/firewall stop
```

I disabled the WAN settings:

```
#config interface 'wan'
#        option ifname 'eth0'
#        option proto 'dhcp'

#config interface 'wan6'
#        option ifname 'eth0'
#        option proto 'dhcpv6'
```

I adjusted the switch to include the WAN port (unsure why ports 0 and 5 are WAN and not just 0) THIS STEP COULD BE MY MISTAKE:

```
#config switch
#        option name 'switch0'
#        option reset '1'
#        option enable_vlan '1'

config switch_vlan
        option device 'switch0'
        option vlan '1'
        option ports '0 1 2 3 4 5 6' # added WAN ports 0 and 5

#config switch_vlan
#        option device 'switch0'
#        option vlan '2'
#        option ports '5 0'
```

The 'lan' interface looks like this:

```
config interface 'lan'
        option ifname 'eth1 switch0'
        option type 'bridge'
        option proto 'static'
        option ipaddr '10.0.1.3' # MAC reservation on main router
        option netmask '255.255.255.0'
```

I could connect and get an IP from the main router, but I could not ping my new router, nor access it over SSH or access the Web UI. What am I missing?

Comment: Just throwing this out there...herein could lie my solution: https://forum.openwrt.org/t/solved-trouble-setting-up-wifi-access-point-dumbap/10627/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turned out to be the stupidest thing.

While this line in my lan configuration appears flawed:

```
    option ifname 'eth1 switch0'
```

and is now just

```
    option ifname 'eth1'
```

The issue has to do with MAC addresses of two physical ethernet devices on the Netgear R7800. My router's dhcp server had a static ip address reserved for the eth0 device and not for eth1.

I opened a follow-up question to tackle the MAC address disambiguation problem here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/479231/33386

To get things working for the time being, I just left the WAN eth0 CPU interface on its own line. I added a new static ip address reservation on the main router for eth1 (keeping the one for eth0 just in case I need it again). I moved the wired connection from WAN to one of the LAN ports and set up the LAN ports as a simple access point only (no DHCP or firewall).